# make wordpress sidebar before the content

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make this sidebar appear before the content when I open the site from the phone, because when I open it from the phone the sidebar is below the content
[image]

I searched but couldn't find the solution

Comment: Do you flex or grid? Can you share a bit of your code or a URL?

Comment: https://haglobalmarketing.com/blue-world-city/

Comment: can u help me or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using flex, you need to use column-reverse which will change the order of elements on mobile. So you need to target the first row of your container (add a class for instance or :first-of-type of first-child) and add this:

flex-direction: column-reverse;

Hope this helps

Comment: Another option instead of `flex-direction: :column-reverse;` you could also use the flex order rule to reorder the containers within a media query. `@media (max-width:767px) { .content { order:2; } .sidebar { order:1; } }`

Comment: Yes that's also a good solution

Comment: Where Should i Write @media (max-width:767px) { .content { order:2; } .sidebar { order:1; } }

Comment: Did you write any CSS somewhere?

Comment: no i didnt write

Comment: You need to click on "Customize" in the admin bar and then click on "additional css" then copy paste the code

Comment: still not working https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5P6y.png

Comment: Try this one instead: @media (max-width:767px) { .bt-content-wrap { order:2; } .bt-sidebar-wrap { order:1; } }